# getting irrelevant data from the server

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to get data from a remote server in an Android application. A php file was created for interacting with the database. However instead of data, I got all structure of the PHP file such as codes and tags...(as you see in the attached picture below).

Please help me.
[image]
*Click to enlarge*

Comment: Where is the attached picture?

Comment: Please attach the picture, and ...

Comment: If you see the actual PHP code when accessing the page, then you've probably not installed PHP and/or configured the web server (you do have a web server, right?) to run/parse PHP.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgSpSm.jpg

Comment: You need to share your code (which fetches the data).

Comment: you were right i'm using a web server but when i run the php file in a explorer i got the right data

Comment: just in my android program i get the whole actual php codes not the real data

Comment: @MagnusEriksson

Comment: The image doesn't show PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The web page you show sets a cookie and then does a browser redirect to http://topapplications.ir/myText.php?i=1 (All in JavaScript) So presumably your tests in Explorer work because they're redirecting.

If your back end needs to do this logic, and your front end can't execute the JavaScript, then I suggest performing the same logic via PHP instead. Either that or point to a URL that doesn't do a redirect.

Set the cookie with [setcookie](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and then do a proper server redirect with status 302 if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @Tim,I got the problem you said, just don't know what exactly I should do. Can you explain the last sentence you said?

Comment: You (or someone else) deliberately wrote that functionality into JavaScript. Write it in PHP instead.

Comment: No, I wrote it as a php file and upload it on my remote host but my rented host didn't use it's own domain I parked my domain on it, the problem is because of this. @TIM